# Android - Managing fragment swapping

Tags: android, android-listfragment, back-stack

My application has an activity A which on creation loads a ListFragment -> Fa.

On selecting one of the items, Fa is added to the BackStack and is replaced with another instance of Fa with a different set of data.

Selecting an item in this new instance of Fa puts it into BackStack and replaces it with a third ListFragment -> Fb, whose layout is different.

Fb is designed to show list in a paginated manner and has 2 buttons at its bottom, (Previous) and (Next).

Now I want that when user clicks on the next button I should display the next page of list using a new instance of Fb, but i do not want to add its previous instance to backstack, so that when user presses the back button on the device, he should be taken to second instance of Fa and not the previous instance of Fb.

I was able to achieve all the forward traversing bits as well as the previous and next button tasks, but now when i press the back button, the second instance of Fa shows up however Fb's last instance does not get removed and can be seen in the background.

How can i remove all instances of Fb and show only Fa when i press the back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the Back button behaviour and 'pop' the back stack up to the desired fragment:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    fragmentManager.popBackStack(R.id.fragmentA, 0);
}
```

`popBackStack` will consume all fragments until it reaches the one which is supplied when called.

Comment: In my case the containerViewId for both Fa and Fb is the same. However the fragment class of the two fragments is different. Is there a way in which i can remove them based on the class of the fragment.

Comment: Ah I see, at the moment the only was I currently have in mind is to assign the two fragments with a tag as you replace/add them, and then pop the back stack with the tag rather than the reference.

Comment: Can you help me with the implementation. Lets say my fragment Fa has the title "Group Health", so i can pass "GroupHealth" as the string tag in addToBackStack(). For my second fragment type i use the title "Drilldown", so for this i can add it to back stack as addToBackStack("Drilldown")....now while popping up should i invoke it like popBackStack("GroupHealth",0) in the onBackPressed()?

Comment: Yep that looks right.
Refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack for more information

Comment: My stack is something like GroupHealth->GroupHealth->Drilldown->Drilldown. Now when i press back my stack should be GroupHealth->GroupHealth. For this do i pass "GroupHealth" or "Drilldown" to the popBackStack() ? Also, do i need to put this in a loop, or will that recursion be handled by popBackStack itself?

Comment: Because you have fragments with the same name it gets a bit difficult, but try using the "Drilldown" tag instead and also using `FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE` instead of the 0

Comment: I guess its working fine now. For the second instance of GroupHealth fragment I am adding the tag "GroupHealthLast" while i am adding it to the backstack. And in onBackPressed, i am doing popBackStack("GroupHealthLast", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE). With this it is behaving as needed. Will test it thoroughly and get back if needed. THANKS